# Security of Moblie Hotspot (4G LTE, WiFi) vs. Apartment Complex Cable Internet

Tags: wireless

The overwhelming majority of my banking is done online. As such, I try to be as cautious as possible. I am moving into a new apartment in a few months which offers internet. (I am not sure whether it is WiFi or direct wire.) Unfortunately, you cannot have your own service exclusive to your apartment: your choices are either (a) no internet or  (b) their internet. Now, I have a mobile hotspot (Verizon Jet Pack), which offers connection to the 4G LTE network via WiFi. In general, would that be more secure than connecting to the internet offered by an apartment complex (especially if it WiFi)? The apartment complex is not “sketchy” by an means; however, I rather be informed! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you could get your own internet if you wanted, there's nothing stopping you from ordering your own ADSL, is there? Regarding snooping there's nothing that your building could be doing that an ISP or 4G LTE network couldn't be doing as well. Your building could keep a log of your traffic and see what you connect to, so could an ISP (depending on where you live this could already be happening). They could inspect unencrypted traffic to see the content, so could your ISP. My main concern would be whether the building forces you through a proxy as that would allow them to read your encrypted traffic as well. Of course an ISP could force you through a proxy but they almost never do.

So if the building is not going to proxy your traffic then it's just the same as using an ADSL or LTE connection. It's unlikely they would do any inspection or tracking - these technologies cost money and this service is probably just a value-add, however it is within the realm of possibility. They probably have a contract and/or AUP you will have to agree to as a condition of using the service, get a copy and read it as it may be illuminating. Also ask the building management for details, they will probably give you all the details you want.

If you are concerned about snooping in general then you should be just as worried about your ISP or LTE provider, they are more likely to be the ones watching what you do. In that case use tor or a similar technology.